# unity injectionconstructor vs injectionfactory laziness

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have registration like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<SOMETYPE>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(Container.ResolveAll<ITYPE>())); <---
```

When `Container.ResolveAll<ITYPE>()` will happen? During registration or rather when first time called?

Is there major difference between `InjectionConstructor` vs `InjectionFactory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When `Container.ResolveAll<ITYPE>()` will happen? During registration or rather when first time called?

At registration, i.e. when you call `RegisterType` and passing an `InjectionConstructor` to it. `Container.ResolveAll<ITYPE>()` is called before the `InjectionConstructor` is initialized and the `RegisterType` method is called.

An `InjectionFactory` accepts a factory `Func<IUnityContainer, object>` which initializes the object when it's resolved from the container:

```
Container.RegisterType<SOMETYPE>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => c.ResolveAll<ITYPE>()));
```

So using an `InjectionConstructor`, an `object` (an `ITYPE` in this case) is created at registration and using an `InjectionFactory` a `Func<IUnityContainer, object>` (which is implemented to return an `ITYPE` in this case) is created at registration.